# Datatype for weekdays in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a list of manufacturers that delivers items on a designated day(s). For instance, manufactuer A might deliver items on Mondays and Thursdays. I need to design a page that displays this information. The page basically contains 7 checkboxes, monday through sunday that the manufacturers can toggle on/off to set their preferred day of delivery.

The table I am creating in my SQL Server 2008 will contain a manufacturer ID, which is integer acting as primary key and a field to store the delivery day.

What is the most appropriate datatype to use for the delivery days?

Comment: Performance isn't a huge issue. I suspect it will contain approximately 500 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a single day is sought;

I would choose `TINYINT` because;

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())
```

will result in an integer ranging between 1-7 (incl)

Assuming multiple days are sought;

EDIT: I think an n:n solution might perform better but haven't confirmed.

Would you be interested in pursuing a solution like this?
I chose this approach because I feel it is "neater" than having an n:n table.
We can expand on it as you expand on your requirements.

```
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.Manufacturer') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Manufacturer
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.DeliveryDays') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE DeliveryDays
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Manufacturer](
    [ManufacturerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Manufacturer] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DeliveryDaysBinScore] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Manufacturer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ManufacturerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE DeliveryDays
(
     WeekdayNum INT
    ,tDayName   VARCHAR(9)
    ,DayBinVal  INT
)
INSERT INTO DeliveryDays VALUES 
(1, 'Sunday', 1),
(2, 'Monday', 2),
(3, 'Tuesday', 4),
(4, 'Wednesday', 8),
(5, 'Thursday', 16),
(6, 'Friday', 32),
(7, 'Saturday', 64)

/*
    Sunday      = 1 = 1
    Monday      = 2 = 2
    Tuesday     = 3 = 4
    Wednesday   = 4 = 8
    Thursday    = 5 = 16
    Friday      = 6 = 32
    Saturday    = 7 = 64
*/

INSERT INTO Manufacturer VALUES
('ABC Co', 16 + 1), ('Boxer PTY', 64+8), ('ConsumeIT', 1+4+16)

SELECT *
FROM Manufacturer   M
JOIN DeliveryDays   D ON M.DeliveryDaysBinScore & D.DayBinVal != 0
```

Comment: I haven't really commented the code, I'm hoping that by doing things like addition in the insert statement, it is clear how the operation functions or that you are familiar with simple binary operations.

Answer (score 1):

**With multiple delivery days:**

The best idea might be to have 7 BIT fields. This has advantages over storing as a single INT or VARCHAR in terms of indexing and the amount of records that needs to be scanned when querying on those fields.

Just for completeness, I should note that MySQL has a variable length binary field (SQL-Server doesn't as far as I know).

The alternative is using a single INT field and using bitwise operations to determine which days are checked (or a VARCHAR if you want to be able to see the values easily when doing `SELECT *`, but you can always have a calculated field or stored proc for this).

**With single delivery days:**

I would just recommend storing an INT that can have a value 0-6 or 1-7.

Comment: SQL Server has VARBINARY(n); this is a variable length binary type. However, there are restrictions on the types allowed in binary operations. AFAIK you are limited to 32bit integer on the RHS. I stand to be corrected.